# Converting Craft CMS to Static Site

Tags: export

I have loved Craft for years and used it for my site. Unfortunately, I will need to convert the site from Craft to static-only because I'm shutting the site down, but want to leave it in archive form as static pages. I would keep it as it is in Craft if I could, but I don't have the time or resources to update Craft anymore or to worry about hacks, etc. And I get emails from hackers weekly asking for payment for finding a bug. Just can't deal with that anymore. I assume they might still send these emails with a static site too, but at least I won't have a login feature with user email addresses in a database anymore - just static pages as an archive. Eventually, I'll probably remove the static site archive too, but I have to do this in baby steps. This site has been my "baby" since 2001, so it's hard to shut down - but it's time. :(

So I'm wondering if anyone else has converted a Craft site to static or if there is any guidance you can give. Thank you! (I did search but didn't find anything about this.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download an entire site (including all of the JavaScript, CSS, and images) with:

```bash
wget -mpk https://example.com
```

It'll even convert the links after everything has downloaded so you can access the site locally.

ref: https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=wget+-mpk+https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Using `wget` as per Andrew's answer may be exactly what you want – another option would be to use [Blitz](https://putyourlightson.com/plugins/blitz) with either the built-in Git Deployer or another [remote deployer](https://putyourlightson.com/plugins/blitz#remote-deployers) to generate a static version of the site and deploy it to Netlify or wherever you want.

When you're ready you can wind Craft down and the static site will continue to exist – letting go is an art.

Comment: Thanks! Yes  - letting go is definitely an art. :)